# Consume web service through JSF application

Tags: web-services, jsf

I have a web service I want to consume it through JSF. I am a beginner in web service I googled it but not found any satisfactory answer can any one pls help.
I have a wsdl link what I need that only with the help of this wsdl file calls the exposed methods.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: ajax would be an easy option but it is better to seperate the webservice logic in a service class

Comment: Actually in my application I have a logic layer which deployed as a service I have to call it through any other java class

Answer (score 0):

Run wsimport tool on your WSDL file (or your WSDL link). It will generate client classes that you can use in your JSF application.

Look for the class that has method getPort() or getPort. It will return the object which is a web service proxy. You can call web service methods on it.

You'll find wsimport in you Java JDK bin directory.